# Laravel @include into master layout results in: PHP Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted

Tags: php, laravel, include, laravel-blade, template-engine

I am trying to include into my master.blade.php a top.blade.php file, but I end up with this error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted
>   (tried to allocate 16384 bytes) in
>   /Websites/Hermann_Sofa/html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/View/Factory.php
>   on line 534

Maybe I am doing something wrong?
Thanks!

route.php:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home');
});
```

home.blade.php:

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/ -->

    @extends('layouts.master')

    @section('content')
        <p>This is my body content.</p>
    @stop
```

top.blade.php:

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/ -->

    @extends('layouts.master')

    @section('top')
      <div class="right col-md-4 pull-right">
        <span class="phone"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-earphone"></span> 0743 443.566</span>
        <span class="text-right" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#loginModal"><span class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></span>COSUL</span>
      </div>
      <div class="left col-md-8 hidden-xs">
        <span class="label label-warning">PROMOTII</span><span class="promo_1"> Promotii speciale de weekend!</span>
      </div>
    @endsection
```

master.blade.php:

```
<!-- Stored in resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php -->

<html>
    <head>
        <title>Sofa</title>
    </head>
    <body>

      <div class="top">
          <div class="container">
              @include('top')
          </div>
      </div>

        <div class="foo">

        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: It seems you have memory leak somewhere, it is you whole code? You can try to change `@stop` to `@endsection`, because you are using different end tag in top and home views. You can also temporarily set higher memory limit by executing `ini_set('memory_limit','256M');` somewhere in the code.

Comment: This is causing an infinite include loop between master and top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you are doing: top extends master and master include top => cause never-end include => cause Memory error.  
**Solution:**
Remove

```
@extends('layouts.master')
@section('top')
```

And

```
@endsection
```

From your **top.blade.php**. That's it